# How can I select a list/tree/table item via right-click and open a context menu at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, contextmenu

When I right-click on an item in a Swing table/tree/list,

- the item should be selected and
- an appropriate JPopupMenu (context menu) should be shown.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using `component.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu)` to register popup menus for my components, which seems to swallow the right-click event so that the targeted item is never selected.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the right-click is indeed consumed by the built-in popup trigger.
To work around this, *override* the `JPopupMenu.show(...)` method like this (sample for `JTable`, `JList` and `JTree` work similarly):

```
public class ExtJPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {

[...]

    @Override
    public void show(final Component invoker, final int x, final int y) {
        if (invoker instanceof JTable) {
            final JTable table = (JTable) invoker;
            final int selRow = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
            if (selRow > -1 && !table.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(selRow)) {
                table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(selRow, selRow);
            }
        }

        // ensure the newly selected item is focused
        invoker.requestFocus();

        // now build the appropriate menu for the selected item
        [...]

        // finally show the menu
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
    }
}
```

Register your `ExtJPopupMenu` instance with your table using `table.setComponentPopupMenu(...)`.